Highcharts ChartEvents not working when configured from C# after upgrade to latest version
Chartevents like load, redraw, onselections, plotseries click etc not trigerring in Highcharts after highcharts upgrade. We are using highcharts dll in .net to create chart objects and using javascript as well for some customizations.
   chart.Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart {
            Events = new ChartEvents
            {
                Load = "initChart",
            },
            Type = ChartType.Column,
            Inverted = false,
            ZoomType = ChartZoomType.Y
        };

This is not triggering initChart method which is in script. For example :
  function initChart() {
                //alert("test");
                this.inverted = true;
                this.redraw(false);
        return
 }

On load event want to invert the chart .. Bar chart should come horizontaly. This is what i am trying to achieve.
function createChartSwapChart() {
var ChartOptions = {
"plotOptions":{"column":{"pointPadding":0.1,"borderWidth":1.0}},
"chart":{"renderTo":"SwapChart"},
"series":[
{"data":[{"y":100.0},{},{},{}],"states":{"hover":{"enabled":false}},"type":"column","name":"7"},
{"data":[{},{},{},{}],"states":{"hover":{"enabled":false}},"type":"column","name":"1"},
{"data":[{},{"y":100.0},{},{}],"states":{"hover":{"enabled":false}},"type":"column","name":"2"},
{"data":[{},{},{},{}],"states":{"hover":{"enabled":false}},"type":"column","name":"3"},
{"data":[{},{},{"y":100.0},{}],"states":{"hover":{"enabled":false}},"type":"column","name":"4"}
],
"yAxis":[
{"min":0.0,"max":100.0,"tickWidth":1.0}],
"xAxis":[
{"categories":["1","2","3","4"]}
]
};
Highcharts.chart("SwapChart",ChartOptions);
}

On investigation i found like when checking the chartoptions generated i am able to see the events object. I also tried multiple events as suggested :
 highChart.Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart
                {
                    Events = new ChartEvents
                    {
                        Load = @"function() {console.log('Chart loaded');}",
                        Selection = @"function (event) { console.log('Selection made:', event); return false; }"
                    },
                    Zooming = new ChartZooming
                    {
                        Type = ChartZoomingType.X
                    },
                    ZoomType = ChartZoomType.X,
                };

I was able to enable zooming through custom script. but we have  implemented many charts and will have to change script everywhere. Is there any generic solution available for the same?
chart.zooming = {
                type: "xy",
                resetButton: {                   
                    theme: {
                        zIndex: 0
                    },
                    position: {
                        align: "right"
                    }
                }                
            };   

Regarding the events it is working when i add the events through javascript but through c# object.
    Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Chart, 'render', function (event) {
        console.log("On Add event Render");
    });

Is there a generic solution for this. Is this a known issue?

The initChart function may not work properly. To change the inverted property, use the chart.update method. For example:
function initChart() {
  this.update({
    chart: {
      inverted: true
    }
  });
}


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b59c4pq7/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

the initChart method is not getting triggered when the ChartEvents ar ecreated from .net  c#. In C# do we have to mention anything specifically or any format to be followed?

Hi @Anju Raman, Please try to add the event directly in chart options, like in this example: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Gallery?demo=DynamicUpdate&theme=default

Hi @ppotaczek i tried the same but when checking in the script generated in RenderHtml i am not able to see events there. It looks like it is not getting added in the script. I am adding my code in the question

Is there any version compatibility for versions of Highsoft.Highcharts and Highcharts.js i need to check for here as the chart events are not working as expected. In the generated chart options events object is not found

Hi @Anju Raman, Sorry for the late reply. To make it work, you need to place the whole function definition in the string assigned to Load. So instead of Load = "initChart" it should be Load="the whole function definition".

Hi @ppotaczek, thank you for your response.  i tried writting creating object as below highChart.Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart { Events = new ChartEvents { //Load = "initChart", Load = @"function() {console.log('Chart loaded');}", Selection = @"function (event) { console.log('Selection made:', event); return false; }" }, ZoomType = ChartZoomType.X, PanKey = ChartPanKey.Shift }; but not working

Hi @Anju Raman, You are right, it doesn't work, sorry for the confusion. There is probably a bug in the current version of the wrapper that prevents the use of chart event callbacks. You can try to use CustomFields with the function name only and keep function definition in JS.

Hi @ppotaczek, i tried implementing it with the customfields but it is still not working for me. I tried adding events like below
                Events = new ChartEvents
                {
                    CustomFields = new Hashtable
                    {
                        { "redraw","onRedraw"}
                    }
                }


Hi @Anju Raman, Ok, I found a workaround. Instead of Highcharts.ID you need to use Chart.RenderTo and it should work.

Should i be using it along with customfields or directly events ?

You can use events directly.

this helped and events are triggering @ppotczek. But there is another issue like zoom is not getting triggered. Should we initialize it separately through script?

I checked and the zoom functionality works properly. You need to set ZoomType like in this example: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Gallery?demo=LineTimeSeries&theme=default

i tried the same but it is not working for the charts. Events are working fine.

is there away to fix the zoom issue. It is not accepting or working as expected. Few places i am able to add zoom through the script. But for few it is not working when added through script also

Hi @Anju Raman, I created a simple example of how you should add the zooming functionality: https://filebin.net/cllo3c6851ijldac Please note that Highcharts doesn't provide support for zooming in all series types.
